# Events and listeners in symfony2, usage of listener services

Tags: events, symfony, service, listeners

I have a listener and i would like to send an event to that listener.
Now this listener should be a global listener, this means that i do not like to intantiate the listener every time i need it, i should just be able to send an event any time to that listener without making it each time. Is this possible ?

```
   myname.listener.mylistener_send:
     class: MyName\MyBundle\Listeners\MyListenerSend
     tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: myListener.send, method: onFooSend }
     arguments: [ @logger, @myListener.helper]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define it as a service and the Symfony DIC will instantiate that listener for you.

Comment: I defined it as a service, please check my updated post for the code, just added the service code. However it seems that it is not being dispatched to the listener

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its under services: namespace in config, it should work. You can try using subscriber class,

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Its fixed by using the $dispatched = $this->get('event_dispatcher');